# Angular 2 D3 tree is not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, tree

I have a tree made with d3 (v3) in plain javascript that I'm trying to transition into an Angular2 component. However I'm having trouble getting it to display correctly.

Here's the contents of my code in tree.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
})
export class TreeComponent {
@ViewChild('tree') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
@Input() private data: Array<any>;

private dataInfo2 = {
  "name": "rootAlert",
  "alert": "true",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Child1",
    "alert": "true",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Child1-1",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child1-2",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child1-3",
      "alert": "true"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Child2",
    "alert": "false",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Child2-1",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child2-2",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child2-3",
      "alert": "false"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Child3",
    "alert": "false"
  }]
}

private values = this.dataInfo2
//console.log(JSON.stringify(values))

//private element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;;
private div = d3.select("body")
        .append("div") // declare the tooltip div
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);
private switcher = true;
private margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 };
private width = 960 - this.margin.right - this.margin.left;
private height = 800 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
private i = 0;
private duration = 750;
private root;
private select2_data;
private diameter = 960;
private tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([this.height, this.width]);

private diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

private svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.right + this.margin.left)
    .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");


ngOnInit(){

  this.root = this.values;
  //values is the flare.json
  //select2_data = extract_select2_data(values, [], 0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
  this.root.x0 = this.height / 2;
  this.root.y0 = 0;
  this.root.children.forEach((item)=>this.collapse(item));
  this.update(this.root);
  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

}



setAllFalse(root){
  if (!root.childAlerts){
    root.severity = false
    root.class = 'nf'
    console.log("set " + root.sourceName + "to false")
    return
  }
  else{
    for (var i = 0; i < root.childAlerts.length; i++){
        this.setAllFalse(root.childAlerts[i])

    }
  }
  root.severity = false
  root.class = 'nf'
  return
}

//recursively collapse children
collapse(d: any) {

    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        //var clps = this.collapse;
        d._children.forEach((item)=>this.collapse(item));
        d.children = null;
    }
}

// Toggle children on click.
click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
    else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    this.update(d);
}

openPaths(paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        if (paths[i].id !== "1") {//i.e. not root
            paths[i].class = 'found';
            if (paths[i]._children) { //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                paths[i]._children = null;
            }
            this.update(paths[i]);
        }
    }
}

openPaths2(paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        if (paths[i].id !== "1") {//i.e. not root
            paths[i].class = 'nf';
            if (paths[i]._children) { //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                paths[i]._children = null;
            }
            this.update(paths[i]);
        }
    }
}



update(source) {
    // Compute the new tree layout.


    var nodes = this.tree.nodes(this.root).reverse(),
    links = this.tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

    // Update the nodesâ€¦
    var node = this.svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d: any) { return d.id || (d.id = ++this.i); });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
    .on("click", this.click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            if (d.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136"; //red
            }
            else if (d._children) {
                return "lightsteelblue";
            }
            else {
                return "#fff";
            }
        })
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
            if (d.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136"; //red
            }
        });

    nodeUpdate.select("text") //NOCARRY
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the linksâ€¦
    var link = this.svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d: any) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", (d) => {
            var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
            return this.diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr("d", this.diagonal)
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
          console.log("d IS")
          console.log(d)
          console.log("AND ITS TARGET IS")
          console.log(d.target)
            if (d.target.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136";
            }
        });

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
            return this.diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d: any) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

searchTree(obj, search, path) {
  console.log("ROOT IS ")
  console.log(obj)
    if (obj.name === search) { //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
        path.push(obj);
        return path;
    }
    else if (obj.children || obj._children) { //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
        var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
            var found = this.searchTree(children[i], search, path);
            if (found) {// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                return found;
            }
            else {//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                path.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    else {//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And here is tree.component.css

```
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.found {
  fill: #ff4136;
  stroke: #ff4136;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

The only thing I've changed from the plain js to this, is to make all the variables part of the TreeComponent class, and have the class methods act on them accordingly . I've tried anchoring the original svg to other elements, but that never renders at all, so here its mounting the svg on the body element. Here is an example of what I see.

[image]

I'm looking for it to resemble this: (How it would render in plain js)
[image]
Anybody have any insight into what's going on here? It looks to me like only one node and path get appended, and it just stops after that.

Comment: First at all, why you don't take the d3 version 4 ? Then, Can you explain precisely what are you trying to do, and what result you want ?

Comment: @pirs Using version 4 would require a rewrite of a fairly large amount of code beyond this. We have a number of niche functionalities that we aren't keen on restarting on with changes that v4 brings. I've uploaded an image of what the visualization is basically supposed to look like.

Comment: It's clearly the best way to understand how to master your code, and there ara a lot of examples all over internet like : https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

Comment: please put a clean code with enough explanation so it can be useful for others as well. There are lots of unused vars and functions in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I've figured out what my problems were.

d3 appends it's own elements to the DOM, and angular 2 doesn't know about this, so when I add the css elements in angular fashion, they're ignored because angular doesn't see the elements that D3 has added. So I had to add the following to so that my css would apply, even to dynamically generated elements from d3:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tree',
  template:`
          <div></div>
          `,
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  //No view encapsulation for D3 components
})
```

After adding this, the component css applies itself.

Now, the other problem I was having was actually pretty simple. I was making false assumptions about what `this` refers to in component methods. That's the root of why only one node and one link was getting drawn.

Comment: I am try your above code and getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tree' of undefined, can tell me how to fix it

Comment: can you please post the modification you made to make this code work?

Answer (score 0):

You can set css

```
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I actually have that already in my css file, which I've edited in above

Comment: Now that I look at it, the css in tree.component.css isnt working, but if i add it with a style tag in index.html it at least fixes the weird black fill effect, I updated the picture above